# Reverse ForeignKey lookup between two apps in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Please note I am new to django and I am asking this question since I didn't find any answers online on it. I'm also not native speaking english, so apologies if my question is not formulated correctly.

I have two apps, Profile and Submission.

Inside `Submission` I have a model called Track (Note the related name in the ForeignKey):

```
class Track(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, related_name = 'tracks')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Inside `Profile`, I have a model called UserProfile

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
```

I have a DetailView for `UserProfile` inside `Profile/views.py`:

```
class ProfileDetails(DetailView):
    model = UserProfile
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(
            UserProfile, 
            user__username=self.kwargs['username'],
        )
```

So inside my template for the DetailView, this should work right? (`object` represents the instance of `UserProfile` displayed by DetailView)

```
{% for track in object.tracks.all %}
{{ track }}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead, I just get nothing. There is no output, why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; `object` here is an instance of UserProfile, which has no direct relationship with Track. You need to go via User, which does.

```
{% for track in object.user.tracks.all %}
```

Comment: I can't believe how dumbfounded I feel now. That one little detail made me spend about 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thank you!